# My Sharpe Ratio computation disagrees with SharpeRation.annualized. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I have daily log returns of my asset and I am trying to calculate a Rolling Sharpe Ratio with a window of 252 days.

I defined my sharpe ratio function in R as:
Annualized simple Returns divided by annualized standard deviation of simple returns.
Then I used apply.rolling of performance analytics for a window of 252 days to
create a time series.

Explicitly, my Sharpe Ratio function is defined as

```
sharpe_ratio <- function(x) {

annualized.return = exp(sum(x)) - 1
annualized.sd = sd(exp(x))*sqrt(252)
sr = annualized.return / annualized.sd
return(sr) 

}
```

And I created my time series from my `returns.ts` using

```
sharpe.ts <- apply.rolling(returns.ts, width = 252, FUN = 'sharpe_ratio')
```

However, when I compare this with the *SharpeRatio.annualized* function in *PerformanceAnalytics* I get different results.

For example,

```
test <- returns.ts[1:252]

SharpeRatio.annualized(test , scale = 252)
sharpe_ratio(test)
```

returns

- 5.251688 for the SharpeRatio.annualized
  and
- 5.259081 for the sharpe_ratio function that I have defined.

I have tried some different combinations, but I cannot figure out
what SharpeRatio.annualized is doing or where the difference comes from much less which one is computing the right thing.

Comment: The formula I see here looks a little different: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/versions/1.5.2/topics/SharpeRatio.annualized

Comment: Ok maybe that's where the problem is. I thought they were the same. The numerator is just the annualized return, computed with the geometric mean. It should be the same as mine, no? In the denominator they take the square root of the standard deviation, which I assume it was a typo because it makes no sense and makes the problem even worse... again, we both have the same expression. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the question?

Comment: Yes. SharpeRatio.annualized takes simple, and not log, returns. The right thing to compute is `SharpeRatio.annualized(exp(test) - 1)`.